# Is there a way to vectorize the portfolio standard deviation in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

My goal is to calculate an investment portfolio's standard deviation.

[image]

I've generated a randomly weighted portfolio of 23 stocks:

```
X = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(23),size=1000)
rand_port_wts = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=data.columns)
```

The matrix is: (1000, 23)

I've generated a covariance table:

```
annual_sec_std_deviation = (daily_sec_return.std()) * np.sqrt(num_trade_dys_py)
```

The matrix is: (23,23)

Because the shape of the matrices, understandable I get a value error:

```
ValueError: shapes (23,23) and (1000,23) not aligned: 23 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)
```

The only way that I can think of solving the problem is by using a loop to pass 1 row of the of the portfolio weights dataframe (rand_port_wts):

```
    tbl = []
for i in range(1000):
    tbl.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(rand_port_wts.loc[i].T, np.dot(annual_sec_covariance, rand_port_wts.loc[i]))))

tbl
```

While this works, it takes forever and it's not elegant. I'm hoping that someone might be able to suggest something that's a little more efficient.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not 100% sure here but try:

`portfolio_vol = rand_port_wts.apply(lambda x: np.dot(x.T, np.dot(cm, x)), axis=1)`

where cm is the covariance matrix

Comment: I think you nailed it. I made one little tweak by taking the root of the lambda function.

Comment: 'portfolio_vol = rand_port_wts.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(np.dot(x.T, np.dot(annual_sec_covariance, x))), axis=1)'